# Stuck in installing Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I want to replace Nouveau with Nvidia driver (specific version is Nvidia binary driver-verison 375.82) via Additional Drivers:

[image: Additional Drivers]

After rebooting, I found Ubuntu stopped at this screen:

[image: blank screen]

I had tried to forbid Nouveau:

`sudo vim /etc/modules`

I commented out the line including Nouveau with '#'. Moreover I wrote:

`blacklist nouveau`

`options nouveau modeset=0`

into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`

Kernel of my Ubuntu is Linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic.

Now, my question is just how to alter driver properly? And how to recover my Ubuntu?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I checked my secure boot state right now, it keeps disabled all the time